# Проблема с использованием класса InterstitialAd

Tags: android, kotlin, импорт, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Есть код:

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;
import ru.druliks.top100currencies.R
import ru.druliks.top100currencies.fragments.CurrenciesListFragment

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        MobileAds.initialize(this)

        mInterstitialAd= InterstitialAd(this)
        mInterstitialAd.adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2700432937693422/4873254868"
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())


        if(savedInstanceState==null){
            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container,CurrenciesListFragment(),null)
                .commit()
        }

    }

    private fun showAd(){
        if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded){
            mInterstitialAd.show()
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        showAd()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        when(item!!.itemId){
            R.id.action_about ->{
                val intent=Intent(this, AboutActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Часть кода подчёркивается красным и я никак не могу понять в чём причина:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно вы используете не ту версию библиотеки и/или не тут библиотеку/доку к ней. Ну или баг студии. Оно компилируется, запускается, не падает? Коли так - баг студии. Иначе - покажите какую доку и версию либы используете

Comment: Если код правильный, то тут должна быть библиотека не старше 19.8.0, если старше или откатите или смотрите доку там в целом все похоже, но есть изменения в названиях методов